# How to I correct this Url(Route)

Tags: laravel-5

**Problem**
     I want to make route of view abc.blade.php and with my this coad route not        hit

```
        echo '<div class="col-md-4 grid-top grid-in thumbnail">
        <a href="{{ url (/singol) }}" class="b-link-stripe b-animate-gothickbox">     

<img width="250" class="img-responsive" src="'.$image.'" alt="Random image"/>
   <div class="b-wrapper">
   <h3 class="b-animate b-from-left    b-delay03 ">
      <span>New Product</span>  
   </h3>
   </div>
       </a>
```

Comment: can you show us what Route you have tried which is not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use href='/singol' and it will work.